# Find the height of the following rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

We have a rectangle ABCD, and a point P on the diagonal AC. From P we see BC at an angle $\alpha$. *Knowing $\alpha$, AP and AB, find BC.*

Here's a probably unnecessary illustration of the problem, with known data in red:

[image: Rectangle ABCD]

I am lost with this, certainly, extremely simple problem. I might use the cosine law to define BC as a function of $\alpha$, PC and PB, but I find no way of finding those latter. I thought of finding PB constructing a parallelogram including sides PB and AP, having BC as diagonal, but I'm stuck there since I, in my poor knowledge on solving parallelograms, I would need the other diagonal of the parallelogram to find PB. On the other hand, I looked where could I transpose $\alpha$ as to express its trigonometric functions using known information, but didn't found anything useful.

Sorry for coming to you with high-school problems (I feel ridiculous to be asking this after three semesters of real analysis, one of complex, and one of linear algebra). I'd appreciate, in addition to a method of resolution, ressources that might help me get a comprehensive approach to planar, high-school like geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find $\angle APB = 180º - \alpha$.
2. Use the sine rule in $\Delta APB$ to find $\angle PBA$.
3. Find $\angle PAB = 180º - \angle APB - \angle PBA$.

then since $\Delta CAB$ is right-angled, $\tan \angle PAB = \frac{BC}{AB}$, so you now have $BC$.

Comment: A shortcut: once you know $\angle PAB,$ you can write $BC = AB \tan\angle PAB$.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut! It was really nice of you to point that out.

Comment: Dobby is a free elf! Really, I was haunted by the idea of not being able to solve this... I clearly need to practice more problems needing the use of the laws of sines and cosines.

Comment: This solution isn't elegant, but I looked and couldn't find one (an elegant solution), although I'd be surprised if one didn't exist.